# typings for object parameters function structure

Tags: typescript, parameters

How to set typing for object style parameters?

I have below function signature

```
private buildURI({ endpoint params }): void {

}
```

now typescript throw error for missing typings, so I have tried this

`private buildURI({ endpoint:string, params: any[] }): void { }`

also

`private buildURI({ endpoint, params }: { string, any[]}): void { }`

but both did not work, only this one works

`private buildURI({ endpoint, params }: any ): void { }`

but it does not seem to be a valid one.

so how to set this method with valid typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method to set "object-styled" (the correct term is *destructed parameters*) is the following.

```
private buildURI({ endpoint, params }: { endpoint: string, params: any[] })
```

It's a known pain-point discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7576).

Of course, you can always define an interface first and then use it.

```
interface UriOptions {
  endpoint: string
  params: any[]
}

private buildURI({ endpoint, params }: UriOptions)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define a type having `endpoint` and `params` props:

```
type BuildUriRequest = {
    endpoint: string,
    params: any[]
}

function buildURI({ endpoint, params }: BuildUriRequest): void { }
```